Replacing d[r]/dt by 0 in expression
The purpose is to recognize d[r]/dt in the expression below, and to make the expression zero. It seems impossible because there is no Time[Power[dt,-1],d[r]] in the expression at the left hand side in FullForm, but is there a way to cope with it?
((2 d[r] d[\[Theta]])/dt^2 )/.d[r]/dt->0   (*the xpression does not return 0*)

(2 d[r] /dt )(d[\[Theta]]/dt )/.d[r]/dt->0 (*this expression does not return 0 also*)


Because the original expression does not have d[r]/dt in it. That is why. You need to use the FullForm.  You could do e /. d[r]/dt^2 -> 0 and now it gives zero. Where e here is your input expression.

Here is an easy way to do this, without needing to use patterns or look at FullForm. If you have expression like this
expr = (2 a*b)/c^2

And you want to replace  a/c by say z, you can not do
expr /. (a/c) -> z

And hope to get 2*b*z/c. It will not work Since internally there is no a/c.
Instead, use AlgebraicReplace to do algebraic replacement instead of using pattern.
This way you do not have to worry about internal form
expr = (2 a*b)/c^2


expr = ResourceFunction["AlgebraicReplace"][expr, a/c, z]


To use this for your examples:
expr = ((2 d[r]*d[θ])/dt^2)
expr = ResourceFunction["AlgebraicReplace"][expr, d[r]/dt, e, {d[r], dt}]
expr /. e -> 0

(* 0 *)

And for your second example
expr = (2 d[r]/dt) (d[θ]/dt)
expr = ResourceFunction["AlgebraicReplace"][expr, d[r]/dt,   e, {d[r], dt}]
expr /. e -> 0

(* 0 *)

Notice in the above, we had to replace d[r]/dt by e first, as it does not like 0 there. Then later replace e by zero (or whatever numerical value you want).
Also we have to help AlgebraicReplace a little by using the third argument telling it the symbols involved. See possible issues in the documentation for this function.
